# Stuck on last part of rings $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 7)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x^2 + 7)$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I am checking to see if the rings $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 7)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x^2 + 7)$ isomorphic?

I want to assume that the two rings are isomorphic and let $f$ be the isomorphism. I can let A = $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 7)$ and can let B = $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x^2 + 7)$. I know that $f(1) = 1$ and then  $f(2)=2$ so then if $f$ truly is an isomorphism, $A/2$ should be isomorphic to $B/2$. I was told that $A/2$ was non-zero but $B/2$ was zero, but I am not sure why this is true. Could someone shed some insight on this last part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $2$ is a unit in the ring $B = \mathbf{Z}[x]/(2x^2 + 7)$: indeed, we have

$$2(-\bar x^2 - 3) = -2\bar x^2 - 6 - 1 + 1 = 1.$$

We now claim that $2$ cannot be a unit in $A = \mathbf{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 7)$. To check this, if $2$ was a unit in $A$, then, there would be polynomials $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbf{Z}[x]$ such that 
$$(x^2 + 7) g(x) = 2f(x) - 1.$$
But this gives us that $8g(1) = 2 f(1) - 1$ which is absurd (on parity grounds).

Thus, the rings $A$ and $B$ cannot be isomorphic.